# Cypress Reading values from a cell in a tab

Tags: css, tabs, cypress

When i try to read values from a single cell in a tab using cypress it returns {specwindow: , chainerid: ch-https://app.trahop.com-218} instead of returning values inside the cell.

This is the line of code which returns the meesage above:
cy.log(cy.get("tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)")) .Im sorry if this is a stupid question but i cant find any way to read the values inside the cell.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML for the webpage you're trying to find the cell on? As well as any functional code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

`cy.get()` does not yield a text variable, but instead yields a Cypress-wrapped DOM element. In order to see the value, you'll need to include it in a chained Cypress command, or yield it into a `.then()` (or similar) Cypress statement.

```js
cy.get('tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)')
  .should('have.text', 'foo');

cy.get('tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)')
  .then(($el) => {
    cy.log($el.text());
  });
```